# struts HTTP request based on token fails with an error "invalid token" in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2

I recently upgraded my struts2 jar files to struts2-core-2.3.16.3 from struts2-core-2.3.1.2
post upgrade , most of my update action which have request token in the request are failing to work.
but the failure is intermittent and not consistent.

But one strange thing is it all works perfectly on my local app engine setup. Its only when I upload to Google cloud they fails to work sometime.

how do I debug this ? when the request fails I get invalid token error page as expected.